# Javascript string does not translate the ' correct

Tags: javascript

I have a small issue trying to put an alert on html string inside javascript.

```
var content = "<li onMouseOver='.alert('test');' id='myid"' class='myclass' >"+pcontent+"</li>";
```

but the result is

```
<li onmouseover=".alert(" test');'="" id="myid" class="myckass" ><p><img src="img.jpg" alt=""></p></li>
```

where is wrong ? i have tried also \' but nothing.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
var content = "<li onMouseOver='alert(\"test\");' id='myid' class='myclass' >"+pcontent+"</li>";
```